# Example satisfying Mangasarian-Fromovitz CQ but not LICQ

Tags: constraint, kkt-conditions

On Wikipedia's page for the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions&oldid=922819290), it is stated that Mangasarian-Fromovitz constraint qualification (MFCQ) is weaker than linear independent constraint qualification (LICQ).  What is a counter-example to the claim MFCQ $\Rightarrow$ LICQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following minimization problem

\begin{eqnarray}
\min &&\quad f(x) ~&= -x &\\
\text{s.t.} &&\quad g_1(x) & =x &\le 0\\
&&\quad g_2(x) & = 2x &\le 0
\end{eqnarray}

which attains the unique global minimum for $x^* = 0$. Note that both constraints are active in this point.

By definition, $\nabla g_1(x^*) = 1$ and $\nabla g_2(x^*) = 2$.

> **MFCQ**
>
> The gradients of the equality constraints are linearly independent at $x^*$ and there exists a vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla g_i(x^*)^\top d < 0$ for all active inequality constraints and $\nabla h_j(x^*)^\top d = 0$ for all equality constraints.

In this case, we can choose $d = -1$ to obtain $\nabla g_i(x^*)^\top d < 0$ for all $i \in \{1,2\}$. We have no equality constraints. It follows that MFCQ holds.

> **LICQ**
>
> The gradients of the active inequality constraints and the gradients of the equality constraints are linearly independent at $x^*$.

At $x^*$, both constraints are active and their gradients are clearly *not* independent. It follows that LICQ does not hold.

We conclude that MFCQ $\Rightarrow$ LICQ is false.

Comment: Extra credit if your counterexample does not satisfy Linear Constraints Qualification, i.e., has nonlinear constraints.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone For extra credit: replace the constraints by $g_1(x) = x^2 + x$ and $g_2(x) = x^2 + 2x$.